# Using opencv for eye movement detection for windows store apps in c#

Tags: c#, opencv

I'm trying to track the movement of eyes using opencv for a windows store app i'm making in `c#`.

i have the live feed from the camera using `MediaCapture`.

i've been looking this up online for so long and i see people referring to [MSOpenTech/opencv](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/opencv) here but i can't follow the instructions because the readme file is outdated.

i also cloned the repository to try and run the sample code and when I run the winrt_universal phoneTutorial I keep getting the erorr :

> The build tools for v120_wp81 (Platform Toolset = 'v120_wp81') cannot
>   be found. To build using the v120_wp81 build tools, please install
>   v120_wp81 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current
>   Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the
>   solution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution..."

i don't know what i'm doing wrong with the sample and i'm not sure how to go about following the instructions for the opencv.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The sample project targets Windows Phone 8.1.

To compile and run it, you need to install Visual Studio 2013 (you can get Community Edition from here: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9863608)

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2013 and still getting error then according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801072/the-builds-tools-for-v120-platform-toolset-v120-cannot-be-found maybe the wrong MSBuild is used.