# Die : PlatformToolset v120 is not installed

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, 64-bit, toolchain, openalpr

I'm trying to install Openalpr on my Windows 10 (x64) laptop following this tutorial [Openalpr for Windows](https://github.com/peters/openalpr-windows) but when I'm on the step **Build a release build for x64 targeting toolchain v120** I get the following error in **Windows Powershell**:

```
Die : PlatformToolset v120 is not installed.
At C:\Users\shama_000\Google Drive\Projects\Git Projects\openalpr\windows\build.ps1:230 char:9
+         Die "PlatformToolset $PlatformToolset is not installed."
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Die
```

I opened the file with Notepad++ to search for the issue and it says this:

```
if ($VXXCommonTools -eq $null -or (-not (Test-Path($VXXCommonTools)))) {
    Die "PlatformToolset $PlatformToolset is not installed."}
```

But at the beginning of the code, in the `param` section I found this:

```
[ValidateSet("v100", "v110", "v120", "v140")]
```

So it should work for any version of PlatformToolset (or atleast that's my logic). I don't know which version I have of this Toolset but I've been searching for this error in the internet and I only find posts about Visual Studio like this one [The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801072/the-builds-tools-for-v120-platform-toolset-v120-cannot-be-found) but the "solution" for this issue is to install a recent version of Visual Studio. Right now I have installed **Visual Studio 2015** so, for the answers in this question, this should work already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for Environment Variables that could mess up my build when I found that I already had this variable: `VS140COMNTOOLS`.

So, when I wrote again the command in Windows PowerShell to build, just changed the PlatformToolset to **v140**:

```
.\build.ps1 -Configuration Release -Platform x64 -PlatformToolset v140 -CudaGeneration None
```

That worked out. The issue was that my build couldn't find any Toolset **v120** because there wasn't any there, the only one was **v140**. So if you have the same issue, search in your Environment Variables for which PlatformToolset your computer is using and use that one.

Comment: I am getting:
```
$ .\build.ps1 -Configuration Release -Platform x64 -PlatformToolset v140 -CudaGeneration None
bash: .build.ps1: command not found
```