# Any idea how to solve this npm SQLite install error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to install SQLite for a package to work, but I keep getting this error. Any idea what the problem is and how I can solve it?

```
C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\discord-emoji-stealer-master\discord-emoji-stealer-master>npm i

> sqlite3@4.0.0 install C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\discord-emoji-stealer-master\discord-emoji-stealer-master\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.0.0/node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.0.0 and node@12.16.3 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(382,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2015 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2015 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\discord-emoji-stealer-master\discord-emoji-stealer-master\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\jacka\\Downloads\\discord-emoji-stealer-master\\discord-emoji-stealer-master\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\jacka\\Downloads\\discord-emoji-stealer-master\\discord-emoji-stealer-master\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\discord-emoji-stealer-master\discord-emoji-stealer-master\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\discord-emoji-stealer-master\discord-emoji-stealer-master\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\discord-emoji-stealer-master\discord-emoji-stealer-master\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\discord-emoji-stealer-master\discord-emoji-stealer-master\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\jacka\\Downloads\\discord-emoji-stealer-master\\discord-emoji-stealer-master\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\discord-emoji-stealer-master\discord-emoji-stealer-master\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.9.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\discord-emoji-stealer-master\discord-emoji-stealer-master\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\discord-emoji-stealer-master\discord-emoji-stealer-master\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jacka\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-04T15_30_37_142Z-debug.log
```

It seems to be a problem with the binaries for SQLite but I don't know exactly what the problem is.

Thanks!

EDIT: So after lots of troubleshooting, I downgraded my node.js version to 12.0.0 and then reinstalled all the packages. This then made the command work as the SQLite libraries were now installed.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be:

```
error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2015 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2015 build tools.
```

You might want to check this one too => [The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801072/the-builds-tools-for-v120-platform-toolset-v120-cannot-be-found)

There is a comment that starts with "Wasted 4+ hours on this."

I hope that would help